# Numpy genfromtxt exclude certain rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a huge data set, with many values. I would like to exclude certain rows I see as containing less accurate information. For instance say I have:

```
     1     150.37265     1.6093940 11986.75879  4343.98486   6345.683      8.535   2458.348      3.069   2554.732      2.205   2011.244      1.855   1665.491      2.055   2229.020     11.092   1159.925     63.576   1238.034     63.029   1513.357     76.582    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    609.524      1.071    430.542      0.779    293.832      0.365    201.463      0.499     88.605      1.054    316.139      2.791    426.547      2.960    659.435      3.337    761.369      2.897    982.764      3.981    915.068      3.799    147.845      2.344    284.971      2.969    413.933      3.471    520.958      3.385    761.208      3.425   1299.578      4.812     27.115      0.127     32.692      0.134   3946.924     11.148      0.000      0.030 27.50304  1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000        -1    0    0    2       230   1   1
     2     150.40848     1.6075042 11126.90527  4298.73779   2326.038      3.374   1683.321      2.562   2624.063      2.233   2718.523      2.144   2892.133      2.693    140.665     61.195    281.988     20.099    427.518     22.779    735.361     37.903    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    -99.999    480.256      2.452   1503.665      6.085   1532.825      5.610   1883.756      5.638   2196.444      4.918    -99.999    -99.999   2087.671      5.736    892.003      5.755   1354.323      6.468   1339.161      6.241   1990.614      6.614   1823.208      5.300    -99.999    -99.999      0.522      0.225     16.993      0.240    -99.900    -99.900      0.000      0.750 12.51440  1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000        -1    1    0   11       295   1   0
     3     150.40550     1.6069111 11198.41992  4284.49414    223.931      3.299    111.582      0.887     94.436      0.678     67.895      0.511     61.085      0.507     64.002      6.935     55.312      8.437     65.572      4.568     88.131      5.368     46.054      0.342     36.760      0.223     20.608      0.206     11.796      0.140      8.360      0.086      6.925      0.100      4.889      0.251      8.405      0.461     10.009      0.460     22.655      0.625     28.231      0.567     34.231      0.754     37.358      0.781      6.587      0.501      7.931      0.507      9.492      0.535     15.271      0.591     30.671      0.695     38.314      0.841      1.864      0.125      4.507      0.130    142.376      9.231      0.000      0.030 17.73935  1.00000  -1.00000  -1.00000        -1    0    0    0       314   1   1
     4     150.39050     1.6043303 11558.18359  4222.49707     33.437      1.502     23.667      0.681     16.188      0.566     11.345      0.410      8.666      0.358      6.252      7.394     16.608      6.876     12.765      1.795     25.299      2.120      6.197      0.216      4.550      0.115      1.558      0.082      0.789      0.064      0.392      0.062      0.305      0.044      0.183      0.065      0.463      0.131      0.906      0.157      1.353      0.177      2.328      0.190      3.503      0.273      4.320      0.300      0.098      0.099      0.257      0.142      0.455      0.152      0.721      0.172      3.101      0.241      5.155      0.342      0.047      0.304     -0.538      0.245     21.609      8.478      0.000      0.750 11.57455  1.00248  -1.00000  -1.00000        -1    0    0    0       322   1   1
```

as a sample of my data set, and I say that row 2 and 3 are not accurate enough, how would I import only rows 1 and 4. I would like more of a general trick as opposed to using comments 2,3 since the data set is very vast.

EDIT: The operation does not have to be done with genfromtxt, if there is another method that does the same thing as genfromtxt but can skip columns as well as rows, that would be great!

Comment: Is the data at least readable? If yes, you can _read it_ whole, and then select what you want via _slicing_.

Comment: Generally it will be easier to remove rows from the array after loading.

Comment: Although if you'd like to skip rows at the beginning or end of the file, you can use the `skip_header=<int>` and `skip_footer=<int>` keyword arguments to `np.genfromtxt`.

Comment: The data is readable, but I would prefer to have an operation similar to the use cols parameter of genfromtxt just so I don't have to waste time on such a large data set reading in all these extra values.

Comment: Just so everyone understands my perspective I have a data set with 68 billion values and I may only need 3000 x 80 values

Comment: It sounds like you know which rows to skip in advance, before you have read any data.  Is that correct?  Or do you have to look at the data in a row before you know whether it should be skipped?

Comment: I do know which rows to skip in advance, but usually in my debug console I get input from the user (me) asking which rows I would like to skip.